# SQL query to find rows where a column value is equal to the sum of tow other columns in the same row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to build a SQL query to find rows from a table where a column value "total cost" is equal to the sum of two other columns "price", "discount" in the same row.

This is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pedido INNER JOIN clientes ON
pedido.clientes_id=clientes.clientes_id INNER JOIN chofer 
ON pedido.chofer_id=chofer.chofer_id WHERE clientes.clientes_nombre
LIKE '%$filtro_nombre%' AND pedido.pedido_fecha LIKE '%$filtro_fecha%' 
AND pedido.pedido_costo = SUM(pedido_descuento + pedido_saldo)
ORDER BY pedido_id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET $offset";
```

The query works removing the part of the SUM():

```
AND pedido.pedido_costo = SUM(pedido_descuento + pedido_saldo)
```

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pedido INNER JOIN clientes ON
pedido.clientes_id=clientes.clientes_id INNER JOIN chofer 
ON pedido.chofer_id=chofer.chofer_id WHERE clientes.clientes_nombre
LIKE '%$filtro_nombre%' AND pedido.pedido_fecha LIKE '%$filtro_fecha%'
ORDER BY pedido_id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET $offset";
```

I don't really know how to SUM two values in a SQL query.

Comment: `AND pedido.pedido_costo = pedido_descuento + pedido_saldo`

Comment: @Siyual Thanks! So simple :_ haha

Comment: `SUM()` is for aggregation (adding values across _rows_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUM` is use to calculate the sum of a particular **Column** not **Rows**. Therefore the way you are using `SUM` won't work. For your requirement. Refer the query below

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    pedido 
INNER JOIN 
    clientes ON pedido.clientes_id=clientes.clientes_id 
INNER JOIN 
    chofer ON pedido.chofer_id=chofer.chofer_id 
WHERE 
    clientes.clientes_nombre LIKE '%$filtro_nombre%' 
AND 
    pedido.pedido_fecha LIKE '%$filtro_fecha%' 
AND 
    pedido.pedido_costo = (pedido_descuento + pedido_saldo)
ORDER BY pedido_id 
DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET $offset";
```